# Decrypt data using CryptoJs

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptojs

I'm using below code to encrypt data using CryptoJS

```js
export const encryptData = (data) => {
    let key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(api.encryption.Key);
    let iv = {
        keySize: 128 / 8,
        iv: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(api.encryption.IV),
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    };
    return encodeURIComponent(CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(data), key, iv));
}
```

And for decrypting the data i used below code. But data is not getting decrypted. However encrypt is working fine.

```js
export const decryptData = (data) => {
    let key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(api.encryption.Key);
    let iv = {
        keySize: 128 / 8,
        iv: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(api.encryption.IV),
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    };
    return decodeURIComponent(CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(data), key, iv));
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong while decrypting?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that when you encrypt you return `encodeURIComponent` string, but when you decrypt you *decode* such string too late.

```
export const decryptData = (data) => {
  let key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(api.encryption.Key);
  let iv = {
      keySize: 128 / 8,
      iv: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(api.encryption.IV),
      mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
      padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
  };
  return CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(decodeURIComponent(data), key, iv).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
}
```

this version, instead, decode data *before* passing it to *decrypt*, otherwise you decrypt something that has been encoded, hence it's not usable for decrypt.

Comment: If i try with above code snippet, i'm getting output as - decrypt -> WordArray.int {words: Array(0),sigBytes:0}

Comment: not sure about that, but do you understand why you *need* to decode `data` *bevore* passing it around? the encrypted data returns an encoded string, and that is the string you need to decode *before* decrypting.

Comment: i'm also not understanding. Is there any other alternative approach?

Comment: if all you need is to encrypt/decrypt with a specific key you can try a webcrypto based library such as secretly (search on github) ... it gives you `obj.encrypt(clean)` and `obj.decrypt(encrypted)` out of the box

Comment: `CryptoJS.AES.decrypt()` expects the ciphertext as a `CipherParams` object or by default as a Base64 encoded string (which is implicitly converted), i.e. the data must not be parsed with the UTF8 encoder, see the documentation https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-input. Instead, the decrypted data must be UTF-8 decoded: `return CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(decodeURIComponent(data), key, iv).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);` - @SnehaBoopal

Comment: @SnehaBoopal I've edited my answer but if you'll write a proper answer I'll remove mine

Comment: Thank you so much its working with the above approach

Comment: proper solution is `export const decryptData = (data) => {
    let key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(api.encryption.Key);
    let iv = {
        keySize: 128 / 8,
        iv: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(api.encryption.IV),
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    };
    return CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(decodeURIComponent(data), key, iv).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
}`